# Issue with compiling Ejabberd TLS support on Mac OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: erlang, osx-mountain-lion, ejabberd

The problem is compiling the TLS part of ejabberd. When doing a "make" I get to `gcc -I/usr/local/ssl/include` and start receiving errors like:

```
tls_drv.c: In function ‘hash_table_insert’:
tls_drv.c:134: warning: ‘SSL_CTX_free’ is deprecated \
  (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1347)
```

Then when it gets to: `gcc -I/usr/local/ssl/include`

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/ssl/lib'
```

So neither TLS or SSL end up getting compiled. Obviously not workable for a production environment.

I have openssl installed, and I have seen posts for other Erlang products with this error saying that I need to modify pieces of the SSL library.

Has anyone else seen and fixed this error. Since so many Erlang developers work on Macs it would seem to me that I can't be the only one.

Comment: Do you have the openssl dev package installed?

Comment: Sorry for not replying faster. How would one install the openssl dev package? I installed openssl through homebrew, do I need to build from source to get this? - Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my previous suggestion was more related to Linux than to Mac OS. I believe you should pass a flag to configure, to indicate the path of where brew installed openssl. Probably `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl`